# Конвертировать string в array

Tags: c#

Как конвертировать Массив в формат объекта, например JSON

Через апишник я получаю массив данных ,но не знаю, как с ним взаимодействовать,  [{"a": "bb", "c": "dd", "e": "ff"}], я пытался прописывать UserGame responseJson2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s2), но пробуя сделать responseJson[0] ничего не получается.
Error: Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "object".

```
 WebRequest reqGET2 = WebRequest.Create(@$"{MyApi}");
                    Stream resp2 = reqGET2.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(resp2);
                    Console.WriteLine(sr2);
                    string s2 = sr2.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А так, почитайте про десереализацию JSON https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to

Comment: `WebRequest` устарел, познакомьтесь с `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать класс для десериализации:

```
public class DataClass
{
    [JsonPropertyName("a")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("c")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("e")]
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Десериализацию можно выполнить таким образом:

```
var str = @"[{""a"": ""bb"", ""c"": ""dd"", ""e"": ""ff""}]";

var objects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DataClass>>(str);
```

Из JSON файла на выходе получится список объектов класса DataClass, к которым, при необходимости, можно будет обратиться по индексу элемента. В вашем случае DataClass - это UserGame

Answer (score -6):

> Convert string to array in C#

```
string str = "Hello world";
char[] charArray = str.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Вообще ответ мимо, и вопрос не оформлен на русском. Смысл отвечать не читая вопрос?

Comment: @aepot, в смысле? Как звучит вопрос? Вы читали название вопроса? Если человек не умеет правильно задать вопрос, это не мои проблемы, я показал ему, как со строки сделать массив чара. В чём проблема?

Comment: @aepot, вам код на русском оформить? Или вы без комментариев не понимаете, что там написано?

Comment: Здесь так это не работает. Если вы видите криво оформленный вопрос, предложите автору его дооформить. А не лепить первый попавшийся ответ. Вы код тоже так же по принципу "будь осторожен в своих желаниях" пишете или все-таки разбираетесь в требованиях сначала? Про русский - здесь есть правила, в первую очередь сейчас они относятся к самому вопросу.

Comment: Ну даже если откинуть все нарушения, с которыми вопрос оформлен, там речь про JSON массив, который выглядит как строка вида `[ элемент, элемент, элемент, элемент, элемент ]`. Вопрос именно про десерализацию JSON. А ответ про что?

Comment: @aepot, там не указанно, что это JSON. Как говорится: "как аукнется, так и откликнется"

Comment: [{"a": "bb", "c": "dd", "e": "ff"}] - это JSON